# Is NTFS USN Journaling Service also enabled in Linux OS when mounted?

Tags: linux, ntfs

Let's suppose I have a Windows 7 machine which USN Journaling service is enabled (for C Drive), and installed on C Drive. And I install any Linux distributions which support NTFS, on D drive. After installing two OS, I can boot up with Linux OS and can mount C drive to get some file or change name, or make a new file on C drive. Then, do these change logs are also logged on C drive's Usnjrnl file?